# SQL Insert Select Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running into a need to run an insert query that's perhaps beyond my expertise.  You'll probably see below I'm like a dog chasing his tail at this point and my code is just not correct anymore.

**Problem 1:** It's just not doing what I need and I'm having a hard time getting it with one query.
**Problem 2:** it seems to execute 4 times for each line in the `BOXES` table.

**My current code:**

```
INSERT INTO [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES_LINES] 
(
    [SALES_ORDER_NUMBER],
    [SALES_ORDER_ID],
    [SO_LINE_NUMBER],
    [SO_LINE_ID],
    [FINISHED_PART_NUMBER],
    [QUANTITY],
    [AOF_BOXES_ID]
) 
    SELECT 
        [SALES_ORDER_NUMBER],
        [SALES_ORDER_ID],
        [SO_LINE_NUMBER],
        [SO_LINE_ID],
        [FINISHED_PART_NUMBER],
        0,
        b.[ID] 
    FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ALL_ORDER_LINES] AS aoL 
    LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES] AS b 
    ON b.[SELECTED] = 'True'
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] AS oL WHERE oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = 'EOSBAB130004'
)
```

I need to `INSERT INTO` a single line of data which contains a selection of data from a few other tables.  The key piece is the final WHERE statement.  I need to get `[SO_LINE_NUMBER]` from the `[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS]` table that's associated to the `[SERIAL_NUMBER]` I provide.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: it's T-SQL I hope

Comment: can you not just: JOIN AOF_ORDER_OPTICS AS oL ON aoL.SO_LINE_NUMBER = oL.SO_LINE_NUMBER AND oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = 'EOSBAB130004'

Comment: Your key is in your statement that its repeating 4 times. You are doing a `LEFT JOIN` with `[dbo].[AOF_BOXES]`. WETHER there is a BOX or NOT you will get a value. Hence the repeating values.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to Join AOF_ALL_ORDER_LINES to AOF_BOXES by a common key. If there is not a common value to connect them, or a value that can be derived from another intermediate table you will not be able to join the tables.  Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES_LINES] 
(
    [SALES_ORDER_NUMBER],
    [SALES_ORDER_ID],
    [SO_LINE_NUMBER],
    [SO_LINE_ID],
    [FINISHED_PART_NUMBER],
    [QUANTITY],
    [AOF_BOXES_ID]
) 
    SELECT 
        [SALES_ORDER_NUMBER],
        [SALES_ORDER_ID],
        [SO_LINE_NUMBER],
        [SO_LINE_ID],
        [FINISHED_PART_NUMBER],
        0,
        b.[ID] 
    FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ALL_ORDER_LINES] AS aoL 
    LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES] AS b 
    ON b.[SELECTED] = 'True' and b.SO_Line_Id=ol.So_Line_Id
WHERE oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = 'EOSBAB130004'
```

We may need more information about the data if this doesn't help

---

Alternative you could use a common table expression to 'fake' the intermediate table to join the two tables:

```
with CTEboL as (
select 'EOSBAB130004' AS ser,'True' AS selected

)

INSERT INTO [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES_LINES] 
(
    [SALES_ORDER_NUMBER],
    [SALES_ORDER_ID],
    [SO_LINE_NUMBER],
    [SO_LINE_ID],
    [FINISHED_PART_NUMBER],
    [QUANTITY],
    [AOF_BOXES_ID]
) 
    SELECT 
        [SALES_ORDER_NUMBER],
        [SALES_ORDER_ID],
        [SO_LINE_NUMBER],
        [SO_LINE_ID],
        [FINISHED_PART_NUMBER],
        0,
        b.[ID] 
    FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_ALL_ORDER_LINES] AS aoL 
    Join CTEbol on aol.Serial_Number=CTEbol.ser
    JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES] AS b 
    ON b.[SELECTED] = CTEbol.Selected and b.SO_Line_Id=ol.So_Line_Id
```

Comment: The boxes table doesn't contain the `SO_LINE_ID`.  If it did I wouldn't be in this predicament :)  I'm trying to get the `SO_LINE_ID` from the `AOF_ORDER_OPTICS` table using the `SERIAL_NUMBER` as a reference.  I'm trying to keep from having to do two queries just because I lack that one piece of information.  It's just bad form.  There isn't really anything connecting the optics table to the rest of the tables.